# Can I add my IBM Notes Traveler account?

Tags: accounts

I'm using IBM Notes Traveler and I'd like to add my account to my phone. Is it possible? How do I add it?

I'm using a Nokia Lumia 920 with Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview.

Answer (score 2):

IBM Notes Traveler accounts have been supported via the built in email+accounts since Windows Phone 8.0 - simply add via settings -> email+accounts -> add an account

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. Windows Phone has built-in support for IBM Notes Traveler.

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Press **email+accounts**
3. Press **add an account**
4. Choose **IBM Notes Traveler**
5. Enter your e-mail address and password then tap **sign in**